# Excel build bar graphs with oddly formatted data

Tags: excel

I am currently working in Microsoft Excel 2011 on Mac OS X. I am given a large amount of data in different tables and need to make 2 variable bar graphs with the data.

I understand that the usual way of orienting bar graphs in excel involves placing the data like so:

```
     a     b
A    1     2
B    3     4
```

However, currently I am going to be working with a lot of data of the format:

```
A    a  1
     b  2
B    a  3
     b  4
```

Is there a quick way to either 1) Convert the data from my format to the correct format, or 2) Build a bar graph (without having to go in and do a ton of customization of the data) with the current format.

Currently the only solution I have working is to manipulate and move the data around and rename everything once the bar graph is made, but this is very cumbersome.

Comment: Can you give more detail about the graph that you are trying to create and which labels to include?  A picture would be good.  Also, how are you creating the graphs?  Manually?  Are you willing to run VBA to automate their creation?  If so, then the format of data matters a whole lot less because you can specify it however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in three steps:

1. Fill in the missing values for your first column. This is a bit manual. If the data is huge you consider writing a quick vba subroutine. At any rate, make the data look something like: [image]
2. Highlight this data and turn it into a pivot table.
3. Structure the pivot table to match your bar graph data format and add a pivot chart:[image]